# Can I direct mysql to include the column header as the first line of a CSV export without using other scripting languages?

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I'm migrating content out of an old proprietary database in a new more structured solution. The new solution asks for CSV files. For approval process -- to be checked by a human eye balls -- I need to have column names as the first line in this CSV file.

```
select b.Title as Title, 
b.listinguuid as UID,
.
.
.
FROM b as biblioRecord
-- more join magic
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/biblio-import.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Given the above snippet form an otherwise larger statement, can I direct mysql to inlcude the column header as the first line?

Comment: Your question is marked as MySQL, are you going to MySQL, or extracting from it? It may make a difference, as the MySQL docs certainly don't suggest it will be easy to export the column headers without some form of scripting.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do this from the mysql console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard

Having looked at the MySQL docs for data output what you are asking doesn't look like it it is possible.

You have some options for data validation.

Assuming you have some form of scripting knowledge you Amy be able to create an internal stored procedure that will output the whole table (including column headings). If memory serves the script language is based in Java (not Javascript).

However why not ask if the validation can be done via a web interface, then there are a large number of tools (php my admin comes to mind) that can be used to view the tables (with header info). PhP myadmin may even be able to output the tables in CSV format for you :)

A better solution, depending on how much data needs to be validated, and what the constraints are, may be to create a dedicated set of validation scripts. This is something that you may be needing anyway as part of the larger project, it could be run after a system upgrade for example. You should talk to the client. In fact the script would be a better way to confirm everything has transfered correctly as it could compare the old and new databases directly, and report any anomalous results.

Other possibilities:

Do you have an XML schema for your your new database structure? If you do you could dump your data into an XML database, then viewing it in something like Xl, or use an xslt to present it in a web page.

Im sure there are other possibilities, but they are all going to involve some work to get to your desired end result. They will all be more time consuming, but will have other potentially useful knock on effects that need to be elucidated and presented to the client.

Personally if you have a lot of data go for some form of validation script, human eyes get tired looking at lote of rows of data, and tired eyes confuse brains and cause mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Not sure the answer really helps you much. Gave your question a +1 as thanks.

Comment: I ended up opening the CSV file in sublime and adding the header row manually. It was easy enough. Your answer helped to get me out of that rabbit hole and unto more productive things! :)

Comment: @Richard : Honestly I was going to suggest that. But figured you had already thought of it. Aslo manual addition does risk a potential error ;)